# PL/SQL wrapping hierarchical query in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, syntax

Appreciate everyone's help, I am very new to `PL/SQL` and am finding the Syntax much more challenging than T-SQL. I have a functioning `PL/SQL cursor` that inserts exactly what I want it to into a table. Next step, I want to wrap it in a stored procedure so I can pass in a single parameter value which would take place of the 'MD01' that is seen in the script with any 4 character string the user inputs.

Problem is when I do this (simple `CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test AS`) I am getting a bunch of errors even though the code worked two seconds ago. What am I doing wrong? The section of code posted below functions perfectly, but I don't know how to correctly wrap it into a stored procedure in PL/SQL.

> ORA-00942: table or view does not exist PLS-00364: loop index variable
>   'EACH_REC' use is invalid ORA-00984: column not allowed here

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test IS
DECLARE
   CURSOR c1 IS SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT
    C.FEE_SCHEDULE
,   C.PROC
,   C.MODIFIER
,   C.MODIFIER2
,   C.PROVIDER
,   C.YMDEFF
,   C.YMDEND
,   C.NEXT_SPAN_DATE
,   C.SPAN
,   C.SPAN_FLAG
,   C.RATE
,   TO_DATE(D.YMDTRANS,'YYYYMMDD') AS YMDTRANS
FROM
(
SELECT
    B.FEE_SCHEDULE
,   B.PROC
,   B.MODIFIER
,   B.MODIFIER2
,   PROVIDER
,   TO_DATE(B.YMDEFF,'YYYYMMDD')    AS YMDEFF
,   TO_DATE(B.YMDEND,'YYYYMMDD')    AS YMDEND
,   CASE WHEN RECURSION_LEVEL = 1 THEN NULL ELSE TO_DATE(B.T3,'YYYYMMDD')END        AS NEXT_SPAN_DATE

,   CASE    WHEN    B.YMDEND = '99991231' THEN NULL
            WHEN    B.RANK2 = '1' THEN NULL
            ELSE    TO_DATE(B.T3,'YYYYMMDD') - TO_DATE(B.YMDEND,'YYYYMMDD') END AS SPAN

,   CASE    WHEN    TO_DATE(B.T3,'YYYYMMDD') - TO_DATE(B.YMDEND,'YYYYMMDD') = '1'   THEN 'CORRECT_SPAN'
            WHEN    B.YMDEND = '99991231'                                           THEN 'CORRECT_SPAN'
            WHEN    B.RANK2 = '1'                                                   THEN 'CORRECT_SPAN'
            ELSE 'GAPPED_SPAN' END AS SPAN_FLAG
--, RANK1
--, RECURSION_LEVEL
,   RATE
,   YMDTRANS
FROM
(
SELECT
    A.*
,   CONNECT_BY_ISCYCLE AS T1
,   sys_connect_by_path(YMDEFF,' ') AS T2
,   SUBSTR(sys_connect_by_path(YMDEFF,' '),1,9) AS T3
,   LEVEL AS RECURSION_LEVEL
FROM
(
SELECT
    SUBSTR(FEE_KEY,3,4)     AS FEE_SCHEDULE
,   SUBSTR(FEE_KEY,7,5)     AS PROC
,   SUBSTR(FEE_KEY,19,2)    AS MODIFIER
,   SUBSTR(FEE_KEY,23,2)    AS MODIFIER2
,   SUBSTR(FEE_KEY,29,12)   AS PROVIDER
,   FEE_KEY
,   YMDEFF
,   YMDEND
,   YMDTRANS
,   DENSE_RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY        SUBSTR(FEE_KEY,3,4)
,   SUBSTR(FEE_KEY,7,5)
,   SUBSTR(FEE_KEY,19,2)
,   SUBSTR(FEE_KEY,23,2)
,   SUBSTR(FEE_KEY,29,12)
ORDER BY YMDEFF) AS RANK1

,   DENSE_RANK () OVER (PARTITION BY        SUBSTR(FEE_KEY,3,4)
,   SUBSTR(FEE_KEY,7,5)
,   SUBSTR(FEE_KEY,19,2)
,   SUBSTR(FEE_KEY,23,2)
,   SUBSTR(FEE_KEY,29,12)
ORDER BY YMDEND DESC) AS RANK2
,   RATE/100 AS RATE

FROM AMIOWN.FEE_SCHEDULE
WHERE 1 = 1
AND SUBSTR(FEE_KEY,3,4) = 'MD01'
) A
START WITH  FEE_SCHEDULE IN('MD01')
CONNECT BY  NOCYCLE
    PRIOR   RANK1           =   RANK1 + 1
AND PRIOR   FEE_SCHEDULE    =   SUBSTR(FEE_KEY,3,4)
AND PRIOR   PROC            =   SUBSTR(FEE_KEY,7,5)
AND PRIOR   MODIFIER        =   SUBSTR(FEE_KEY,19,2)
AND PRIOR   MODIFIER2       =   SUBSTR(FEE_KEY,23,2)
AND PRIOR   PROVIDER        =   SUBSTR(FEE_KEY,29,12)
AND LEVEL                   =   2
ORDER BY PROC, YMDEFF, LEVEL
) B
WHERE 1 = 1

AND RECURSION_LEVEL = 2
OR (RECURSION_LEVEL = 1 AND CASE WHEN RECURSION_LEVEL = 1 THEN NULL ELSE TO_DATE(B.T3,'YYYYMMDD')END IS NOT NULL  )
OR  B.YMDEND = '99991231'
OR  B.RANK2 = 1
) C

INNER JOIN
(
SELECT
    SUBSTR(FEE_KEY,3,4) AS FEE_SCHEDULE
,   MAX(YMDTRANS) AS YMDTRANS
FROM AMIOWN.FEE_SCHEDULE
WHERE SUBSTR(FEE_KEY,3,4) = 'MD01'
GROUP BY SUBSTR(FEE_KEY,3,4)
) D ON C.FEE_SCHEDULE = D.FEE_SCHEDULE

WHERE    1 = 1
);

i NUMBER:= 0;
BEGIN
  FOR each_rec IN c1 LOOP
INSERT INTO SCHEMA.FEE_SCHEDULE_GAPS_DETAIL
(
    FEE_SCHEDULE
,   PROC
,   MODIFIER
,   MODIFIER2
,   PROVIDER
,   YMDEFF
,   YMDEND
,   NEXT_SPAN_DATE
,   SPAN
,   SPAN_FLAG
,   RATE
,   YMDTRANS
)
VALUES
(   each_rec.FEE_SCHEDULE
,   each_rec.PROC
,   each_rec.MODIFIER
,   each_rec.MODIFIER2
,   each_rec.PROVIDER
,   each_rec.YMDEFF
,   each_rec.YMDEND
,   each_rec.NEXT_SPAN_DATE
,   each_rec.SPAN
,   each_rec.SPAN_FLAG
,   each_rec.RATE
,   each_rec.YMDTRANS
);
i:= i+1;

  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Comment: This is not a CREATE OR REPLACE statement so is it the actual code which throws the error?

Comment: Your code distinguishes the source table schema (`"AMIOWN"`) from the target table schema (um, `"SCHEMA"`). Does this mean the owner of the stored procedure is different from either or both of these schemas? If so, how does the procedure own have privileges on these tables? How have they been granted SELECT and/or INSERT? This matters because ORA-00942 can indicate a permission problem.

Comment: Why are you going for a row-by-row (aka slow-by-slow) approach here, when you could do all the work in one go (aka set-based) by simply doing `insert into <your table> (<your table's columns>) <your select query>;`? Then it's just a matter of plugging that into the body of your procedure and making sure you have the correct privs (as pointed out by APC!)

Comment: 1) I took out the CREATE OR REPLACE statement piece as it wasn't functioning, and I wanted to show the code that was. 2)In regards to AMIOWN I only have SELECT Permissions to this schema, but in SCHEMA I would have INSERT Permissions.   3) In regards to doing this the slow way I 100% know!  I couldn't get the insert syntax to work (I tried for seriously over an hour) I kept getting the table/view does not exist error.  I finally got this cursor approach to not throw the error, only to have it break again when I created the stored procedure.

Comment: It sounds like you (or more accurately, the schema that owns the procedure you're trying to create) has the permissions granted on the other schema via a role. Procedures that are authid definer (the default) won't look at roles to determine if the necessary privileges are in place - instead, the grants need to be direct - ie. instead of `grant select on schema1.table1 to some_role; grant some_role to schema2`, it has to be `grant select on schema1.table1 to schema2`.

Answer (score 1):

Boneist was correct:
"Procedures that are authid definer (the default) won't look at roles to determine if the necessary privileges are in place - instead, the grants need to be direct - ie. instead of grant select on schema1.table1 to some_role; grant some_role to schema2, it has to be grant select on schema1.table1 to schema2"

I reached out to our Oracle DBA's and they quickly granted me direct access and the stored procedure compiled completely and correctly. Thank you SO much, glad I am not crazy.

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous block:

```
DECLARE
  <declarations>
BEGIN
  <actions>
END;
```

can be converted to a stored procedure this way:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test IS
  <declarations>
BEGIN
  <actions>
END;
```

Comment: When I change the code, replacing my DECLARE anonymous block with a CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test IS I get the "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist error." In addition to the "loop index variable 'EACH_REC' use is invalid" Error.